# Is it possible to call a function which was added by Add-Type using its namespace and name?

Tags: powershell

I am using a kernel function like this:

```
$defText = '[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]public static extern uint SetThreadExecutionState(uint esFlags);'
$def = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $defText -PassThru -Namespace myNameSpace -Name myName
$def::SetThreadExecutionState(0)
```

I wonder if it's possible to call the method by namespace and name (without using -PassThru)?

```
$defText = '[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]public static extern uint SetThreadExecutionState(uint esFlags);'
Add-Type -MemberDefinition $defText -Namespace myNameSpace -Name myName
myNameSpace::myName(0)
```

Of course it says the command was not found. Is it possible to call the method by namespace and name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the defined type `[myNameSpace.myName]` literally e.g. as follows:

```
$defText = '[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]public static extern uint SetThreadExecutionState(uint esFlags);'
Add-Type -MemberDefinition $defText -Namespace myNameSpace -Name myName
[myNameSpace.myName]::SetThreadExecutionState
```

> ```
> OverloadDefinitions
> -------------------
> static uint SetThreadExecutionState(uint esFlags)
> ```

Comment: Great, that saves me one variable.